# Making a link to an external site and downloading a file simultaneuosly

Tags: html

here's what I have so far but it downloads aff.php and then stops because there is no file in my FTP.

```
<a href="https://www.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47" href="structure.zip" download="structure.zip" class="download"><button>Download</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, is remove the first `href` (`href="https://www.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47"`) and replace it with `onclick="window.open('https://www.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47')"`. That way you could have it open the page and download the file.

Comment: is this it <a onclick="window.open('https://www.order.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47
')" href="structure.zip" download="structure.zip" class="download"><button>Download</button></a>